# Do you need to clear a register before using la in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

We are taught to always clear a register before using it, or to treat it as if it may already contain data that could affect the operation we are trying to perform on that register. If I use the `la` instruction, does it overwrite whatever was in that register so it wouldn't matter if it already has data in it?

Would an `or` operation or `and` operation be able to do the same thing as `la`? Is there a better way to load an address than `la`? It is what I most often see for that type of operation but I feel like maybe once before I used `or` instead.

I know some instructions are pseudo-instructions and not as fast or desirable. What is the preferred method?

Comment: Setting a register to `0` right before another write-only access setting it to some other value just clutters up your code with noise.  Don't do that.

Comment: Unless you're using a PDP-8...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`la` is a pseudo-instruction, so it's up to each assembler if and how they want to implement it. But I would say that it's typically implemented as `lui` + `ori`, or `lui` + `addiu`. Both of those combinations will affect all bits of the destination register without any dependency on the old value.  (They start with `lui`)

> We are taught to always clear a register before using it

That sounds like strange advice. Clear a register if you have to, otherwise don't. MIPS doesn't have partial registers like the x86.

Setting a register to `0` right before setting some other value just clutters your source code and makes your program slower.  Two write-only accesses in a row to a register are pointless.

> Is there a better way to load an address than la?

No, not really. That's the most convenient way. And unless the assembler is doing something stupid it will almost always also be as efficient as any handcoded method.  (Except for taking advantage of the displacement bits in an `lw` instruction, but MARS doesn't provide a way to do that other than hard-coding numeric addresses.  See comments.)

Comment: `la` materializes the full address (including the low half) in a register.  `la $t0, symbol` + `lw $t1,  0($t0)` probably assembles to 3 instructions, leaving the 16-bit displacement in `lw` unused.  MARS / SPIM don't have convenient `%lo(symbol)`  and `%hi(symbol)` that would let you manually implement `lui` / `lw` in 2 instructions, or reuse one `lui` across multiple `lw` instructions.  But compilers do know how to do the former:  https://godbolt.org/z/fJEZx7

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `la`, it's more common to use `addi`. You have always do one of those two because if you don´t do them, the variables will have trash inside them and not specific values. `or` or `and` should only be used in a condition statement.

Comment: I assume the OP meant `ori`; some MIPS assemblers let you write `or $v0, $t0, 1234`.  But how exactly are you proposing that you could use `addi` to generate an address in a register?  MARS doesn't have `%lo(symbol)` to get the low half of a symbol address, so you'd need to manually hard-code the numeric address.  If you're doing that you might as well optimize it into an `lw`